# POST request is in ISO-8859 after High Sierra update

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, leiningen, macos-high-sierra

I make web apps using Clojure and ClojureScript, compiling with Leiningen.

My problem is that after updating macOS to High Sierra, my compiled app works fine in my system, but after copying it to the Linux server, POST parameters go ISO-8859.

For example "pöttyös bögre" to "P?tty?s b?gre". That affects every transaction between client and server of course, email sending, writing to database etc. I clean installed Sierra, and then it worked. Updated it back to High Sierra, doesn't work again on the Linux server. I tried clean installing with case-sensitive APFS, and it still doesn't work.

Does anybody know what would cause this?

Comment: Did you try checking your environment variables like `LANG`, `LC_ALL`, `LC_CTYPE`? JVM uses default OS encoding and language settings when it's not set explicitly via system property called `file.encoding`. You can check which is effective in JVM by calling `(java.nio.charset.Charset/defaultCharset)`  (e.g. from REPL).

Comment: TMPDIR=/var/folders/1j/y9ybcqr17dz43_qx9x0z_0900000gn/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.OjaxnOp3ZP/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=400
OLDPWD=/Users/paulcristian/Desktop
TERM_SESSION_ID=BE32A3C2-6E67-454D-A8D6-9F698C53F090
USER=paulcristian
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.KEm79W7GuJ/Listeners
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PWD=/Users/paulcristian/Desktop/garaiker
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/paulcristian
LOGNAME=paulcristian
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
SECURITYSESSIONID=186a6
seems good to me :)

Answer (score 0):

SSH sends the locale to the remote. So my problem was that my locale wasn't UTF-8. Setting up the locale resolved my problem.